# What EC2 Instance type(ubuntu) suitable for media-based application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm creating a web application that lets user upload any size of any audio formats, also uploads image and videos. with an estimated of 500 users per month.

For now, I am still using the free tier instance, and when I upload multiple audio files the request fails and returns `413 Payload Too Large`.

I expected this to happen since free tier instance specs are not intended for heavy processes.

What I wanted to know is that what instance type should I select intended for my app process.

I've read about `r-family`, `x1-family`, `High Memory`, and `z1d` instance types are `Memory Optimized` instance types.

However, I still don't know if this is the suitable instance types to use. or should I just use `t3.medium` or `t3.large`.

Can someone enlighten me on this one?

Comment: This error is more due to your webserver setup, not instance type. For example, nginx has dedicated options for upload size.

Comment: @Marcin I see, i'll check

Comment: @Marcin one question tho, does scaling up my ec2 instance provide better performance on my website given a user of 500 and above?

Comment: Its impossible to answer. You have to check metrics of your instance. CPU usage, ram usage, latency ..., and then decide. Its highly use-case specific.

Comment: @Marcin so i need to start with a smaller instance type and observe the performance before jumping to a bigger instance type right?

Comment: That's how it is usually done.